# Write path of the file chosen in the FileDialog

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I've made a WindowsForms program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace FormChooseFolder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
                Title = "Browse Text Files",

                CheckFileExists = true,
            };


            this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            this.openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Files";

            DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("C:\\test.txt");
                txt.Write(dr);
                txt.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which should write the path of the file chosen to **test.txt** but it instead writes **OK**.
Is there any way I can make it show the path of the chosen file like this `C:\Pictures\banana.png` ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing object of `DialogResult` to `test.txt` store `FileName` selected by user like,

```
DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
     TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("C:\\test.txt");
     txt.Write(dr.FileName);  //Use FileName property to get entire file path
     txt.Close();
}
```

---

MSDN documentation: [FileDialog.FileName Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_FileName)

> Gets or sets a string containing the file name selected in the file
> dialog box.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'DialogResult' does not contain a definition for 'FileName' and no accessible extension method 'FileName' accepting a first argument of type 'DialogResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) FormChooseFolder

Comment: `FileName` is a property not a method, can you show how you are calling `FileName`